# What is preventing this question from being opened?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Politics Stack Exchange post: [The founders of America had a belief that men should be armed as an hedge against tyranny?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42557/the-founders-of-america-had-a-belief-that-men-should-be-armed-as-an-hedge-agains)

It seems that my question is too subjective. How would I frame it in a neutral way without removing any references to despotism?

Comment: Isn't a question about the intentions of a group of people 200 years dead a better fit for History.SE? Politically, today, the intentions of these people matter little alongside two centuries of jurisprudence and technological change.

Comment: @Jontia The time stretch is insignificant when words on paper can create an entire culture regardless of technological change. Politically, it should matter.

Comment: The question is unclear, with the bevy of double negatives. The three cases asked about are rather broad as well. Largely, this question is in the gray area between History and Politics, trending more towards the former. It would be a review of period documents and rationale, with the Federalist and Anti Federalist papers leading the way, building the answer.

Comment: Then, the question is confounded by the conspiratorial nature of your comments in defense of it. There seems to be a deeper question that you're wanting to lead towards, but this is the starting point for the conversation.

Answer (score 2):

The question will likely be on topic in the [History SE](http://history.stackexchange.com) *provided that you do (and exhibit) prior research on the topic*. If you do not do the latter steps expect downvotes and close votes for the same reasons. In particular: cite a few sites you ran into while researching the question.